# Inheritance from Vector::Vector base class

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to learn about inheritance in C++. I am trying to make a subclass of `vector::vector` that only takes `string` pointers.

My grip on pointers and references is admittedly weak, but I can't for the life of me work out why the following code is setting each `string` to the same address:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class StringVector : public vector<void*> {
public:
    void push_back(const string* str) {
        vector::push_back(&str);
    }
    string* operator[](int pos) {
        return (string*)vector::operator[](pos);
    }
};

main() {
    StringVector sv;
    string str1 = "hello";
    string str2 = "world";
    sv.push_back(&str1);
    sv.push_back(&str2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        cout << sv[i] << " ";
}
```

When I run as is, I get:

```
0xffffcb68 0xffffcb68
```

i.e. same address.

When I try to deference the `sv[i]` (i.e. `*sv[i]`); I get an exception. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function

```
void push_back(const string* str) {
    vector::push_back(&str);
}
```

you didn't push the address of the string - you pushed *the address* of the pointer to string.  And in successive calls, the two different pointers were likely stored in the same place (albeit at different times).

Because your vector takes a `void*` and any pointer can convert to `void*`, your compiler didn't have a chance to alert you to your error.  What you probably want is to use a `std::vector<std::string*>` or `std::vector<const std::string*>`.  You [shouldn't inherit from the standard collections](/q/4353203); prefer to use them as members instead.

Consider this a lesson in the dangers of `void*` and of casts!

Comment: Am I the only one who gets very quickly confused by pointers and references? I used to think I was intelligent!

Comment: Pointers are confusing - don't be put off!  Luckily, you don't have to deal with them directly as much in modern C++ as in C++03 and older.  There are good resources written by people with hard-won experience - and you're doing the right thing by experimenting and learning from doing.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to mix inheritance and pointers until you're comfortable with both individually, of course - it helps if you can narrow your problems down to just one area of ignorance!

Comment: I bought Effective Modern C++ (Scott Meyers) the other day - but it is really for someone who already knows C++; so I'm running through Thinking in C++ (Bruce Eckel), which I think is a bit older. If there are any standout references that I should be reading - please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

You're pushing `&str` which takes the *address* of the pointer, so the type you're pushing is `string**`. What's more, you're storing address of a short-lived variable (pointer) - it gets destroyed as soon as you leave your overloaded `push_back`.

The immediate fix is to simply change the `push_back` method (remove `const` on string and pass the pointer to `vector::push_back`):

```
void push_back(string* str) {
    vector::push_back(str);
}
```

which is as good as simply removing the method altogether and using the inherited one.

That being said, it's a bad idea to inherit from most standard containers. You can have a `vector` of `string` pointers just by typing `vector<string*>`.

And if you want to print the string values instead of pointers, you need to dereference them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << *sv[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and advice. I tried that but then I get `no matching function for call to 'push_back(const string*&)`.

Comment: @TobySpeight *facepalms*. Right. Edited.